# Proof by contradiction that $(\ell^p)^* \subseteq \ell^q$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

For $p \in (1, \infty)$, let $\ell^p = \{(x_n) : \sum |x_n|^p < \infty\}$ and let $(\ell^p)^*$ denote the dual space of bounded linear forms on $\ell^p$ $(\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R})$.

It is straightforward to show that (up to isometric isomorphism), that $\ell^q \subseteq (\ell^p)^*$, but I had more difficulty with proving the reverse inclusion. I thought that it would be easier to prove the contrapositive: $$(y_n) \not \in \ell^q \implies \sup_{||\textbf{x} ||_p \le 1} {\sum |x_n y_n|} = \infty$$

but this defeated me, and the other proofs I have seen since prove the result directly.

Thus, I have two questions. Is there a proof by contradiction of the form described above? (I assume not.)

And more crucially, if I am correct in assuming that there isn't, what are hints that a constructive approach is likely or unlikely to work for problems in analysis?

For instance, it now seems to me that the space of possible $(y_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} \setminus \ell^q$ is probably too vast and irregular to try to construct something suitable for an arbitrary choice.

Comment: What I would try is a sequence of $(x_n)$ of the form $(c_1y_1^{q-1},0,0,…), c_2(y_1^{q-1},y_2^{q-1},0,0,0,…), c_3(y_1^{q-1},y_2^{q-1},y_3^{q-1},0,0,…),…$ where you choose your $c_k$ so that the $\ell^p$ norm is at most 1. This might get you to the desired contrapositive statement.

Comment: @Nick I tried that, but the issue is that if you pick constants such that $||\textbf{x}|| \le 1$, you just get that the sum $\sum |x_n y_n|$ is $\le 1$ as well. The direct approach made some subtleties in the reasoning clearer to me. I'm mostly interested in the answer to the second question.

Comment: (Of course, I may have missed some further trick that makes it work.)

Comment: Direct proofs have the advantage, that the norm of the functional is calculated on the way.

Comment: @Nick My mistake, it does work. It's unbelievable how I could have the right idea and still get it wrong, but I guess that is the danger inherent in not writing down every step. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nick's idea works, for the first question at least. We let:
$$\mathbf{x}^n = (y_1^{q-1}, y_2^{q-1}, \ldots, y_n^{q-1}, 0, 0, \ldots),$$
and define
$$\mathbf{u}^n = \frac{\mathbf{x}^n}{\|\mathbf{x}^n\|_p}.$$
We then have
$$\langle \mathbf{y}, \mathbf{u}^n\rangle = \frac{1}{\|\mathbf{x}^n\|_p}\sum_{k=1}^n y_k^q.$$
Note that,
$$\|\mathbf{x}^n\|_p = \left(\sum_{k=1}^n y^{pq - p}_k\right)^{1/p} = \left(\sum_{k=1}^n y^q_k\right)^{1/p},$$
hence
$$\langle \mathbf{y}, \mathbf{u}^n\rangle = \left(\sum_{k=1}^n y^q_k\right)^{1 - 1/p} \to \infty.$$
Thus, $\langle \mathbf{y}, \cdot \rangle$ is not a bounded linear functional on $\ell^p$.

Comment: Thanks, Theo. I believe that you meant to write $\textbf{u}^n$ in the third and fifth equations. But I see now that I was making a much graver error when I was trying to follow this line of reasoning.